# Changing the a HTML file Icon

Tags: google-chrome, browser, webbrowser-control

[image]

I wrote a program with HTML and Javascript and I want to change the index file Icon from my default browser as shown in the image attached to a custom jpeg, I was wondering if that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows shows your default file opener as the icon (in this case, Chrome is the default file opener for .html files). Since this isn't a packaged application (e.g. .exe), you can't specify an icon for it.

You could create a shortcut for it and change the icon by right clicking on it, selecting properties and 'change icon', but that would only reflect the new icon on the shortcut, not the original file.

Comment: That's actually a very good solution since I will have the index files with the material in a separate folder, thank you.

Comment: @BabylonCS, if the solution this user proposed solved your problem, consider marking the response as correct with the green check mark. This way, other users can quickly identify this solution as something of value.